# Code snippets for iOS?

Tags: ios, ios4, code-snippets

xcode4 provide the awesome tool for collecting code snippets. As iOS developer, I am seeking more good code snippets.

So put this question here for more clues for good codes snippets for iOS.

Thanks for your comments or clues.

Answer (score 1):

I add code snippets that contain delegate methods for many of the delegate protocols, for example `UIScrollViewDelegate` or `UIWebVIewDelegate`. I also put little bits of demo code in there to remind me how to use certain things like, say, `MFMailComposeViewController`. When I have the time I put them on my website so that others can use them [idz' Code Snippets](http://iosdeveloperzone.com/category/code-snippets/)